# Mathematica add line to manipulate

Tags: manipulate

```
Manipulate[ Plot[x^2 - 2 (m - 1) x + m (m - 3), {x, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> p], {m, -10, 10, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {p, -50, 1500, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I have this and am trying to add a line on the output graph with the following slope and intersection

```
y=-13.3871 + 0.774194 x
```

I've tried to add a grid line of this line, but it will only work for vertical and horizontal lines it seems.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To get started:1) take [the introductory tour now](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour),2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up [by clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work),4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: A question: if I try to execute the following I get a `Plot`. Can you please try it to see if this is what you want? Perhaps I misunderstood your question. The command is: `Manipulate[
 Plot[{x^2 - 2 (m - 1) x + m (m - 3), -13.3871 + 0.774194 x}, {x, -30,
    30}, PlotRange -> p], {m, -10, 10, 0.25, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {p, -50, 1500, 50, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative the following produces the same output as the code by @cvgmt

```
Manipulate[  Plot[{x^2 - 2 (m - 1) x + m (m - 3), -13.3871 + 0.774194 x}, {x, -30,     30}, PlotRange -> p], {m, -10, 10, 0.25,    Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {p, -50, 1500, 50,    Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Epilog` to add a line `InfiniteLine[{0, -13.3871}, {1, 0.774194}]` with direction `{1, 0.774194}`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[x^2 - 2 (m - 1) x + m (m - 3), {x, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> p, 
  Epilog -> InfiniteLine[{0, -13.3871}, {1, 0.774194}]], {m, -10, 10, 
  0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {p, -50, 1500, 50, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```